# have been or had been with "in 2020"

Tags: grammar

According to a report from 2020, one in ten Americans have (or had?) had a pet...

Should I use have or had when I specify the report is an 'old' report, but the report result should still hold today 2021, given the time difference and based on my knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

If you claim that 10% of Americans own a pet today you can use the present tense.  Your claim is supported by evidence from 2020.  But it is not proved.

If you are claiming that it was true in 2020 and don't claim that it is still true today then use the past tense.

The evidence that it was true last year is slightly stronger, as you have that study.  But you might still want to claim that it is still true, even though you don't have direct proof of this.

So what do you want to claim?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get your point. Since the report is from 2020, based on my knowledge and given the time difference, the result is likely to hold until today 2021 (although it's not directly proved).

Comment: That is my point.  Since you say "based on my knowledge the result is likely to hold today" your claim is that 10% of Americans own a pet.  Your evidence is about 2020, but you may (implicitly) claim that that is recent enough for you to say "10% own a pet."  But this is your claim.  I can't tell you what to say, because you have to decide what you want to say.